# Object of type CharField is not JSON serializable problem

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Creating my first CRUD in Django Rest framework this error keeps popping up. Does anyone know how to fix?? [Object of type CharField is not JSON serializable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycPbQ.png)

models:

```py
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True),
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200),
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True),

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

serializer:

```py
class PessoaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pessoa
        fields = ('id', 'nome', 'cpf')
```

view(set):

```py
class PessoaListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = PessoaSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Pessoa.objects.all()
        ocorrencia = self.request.query_params.get('ocorrencia')
        if ocorrencia is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pessoa=ocorrencia)
        return queryset
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: i've posted the code fragments rn, can you help me?

Comment: How do you use the serializer? Can you share the view(set)?

Comment: edited again with the viewset section

Comment: Why there is a `,` every end of model fields

cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True),

Comment: remove the trailing comma, make migrations and rerun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "Object of type CharField is not JSON serializable" typically indicates that Python is attempting to serialize an object that cannot be directly converted to JSON format. However, in the Django Rest Framework (DRF), CharFields should be serializable by default.

Try this changes:

```
# models.py

class Pessoa(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # Removed comma
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # Removed comma
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)  # Removed comma

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

# serializer.py

class PessoaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pessoa
        fields = ('id', 'nome', 'cpf')

# views.py

class PessoaListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = PessoaSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Pessoa.objects.all()
        ocorrencia = self.request.query_params.get('ocorrencia')
        if ocorrencia is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pessoa=ocorrencia)
        return queryset

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```